# Unable to get Xpath for an input tag on a form

Tags: selenium, text, input

I am not able to get the `Xpath` for an input file with `Selenium`.
Here is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBMtI.jpg) (of the mark-up).

Comment: Why are you unable to get the `xpath`? What have you tried? Does this work `//input[@name='file']`? Image links go stale, and some people can't view them on their networks. If possible, put the html in the question. Cheers :)

Comment: I have tried this ..it doesn't work.i have to click on browse button to upload a file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a frame in your html code, first you have to switch to that frame.

WebDriver's `driver.switchTo().frame()` method takes one of the three possible arguments:

- A number.

> Select a frame by its (zero-based) index. That is, if a page has three
>   frames, the first frame would be at index 0, the second at index 1 and
>   the third at index 2. Once the frame has been selected, all subsequent
>   calls on the WebDriver interface are made to that frame.

- A name or ID.

> Select a frame by its name or ID. Frames located by matching name
>   attributes are always given precedence over those matched by ID.

- A previously found WebElement.

> Select a frame using its previously located WebElement.

Get the frame by it's id/name or locate it by driver.findElement() and you'll be good.

- Then you can perform any action on input tag using below cssSelector :

`driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[name=file]"));`

And after performing your action don't forget to swith it to default frame :

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

**Exception Handling** 
You can wait for the alert to come for 30 seconds using below code , once the alert is present you can easily accept it.

```
try {
    WebDriverWait waitAlert = new WebDriverWait(wb, 30);
    waitAlert.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
    wb.switchTo().alert().accept();
} catch (Exception e) {
    logger.info("Alert Didn't Come");
}
```

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[name=file]"));       didnot work

Comment: after performing some actions on that frame I used driver.switchTo().defaultContent(); but i am getting an error Modal dialog present

Comment: Added exception handling.

Answer (score 2):

Since the element you want is inside an `iframe`, you will have to switch selenium's focus to the iframe and then use the xpath to fetch the element.

**JAVA**:

To switch to the iframe, use

`driver.switchTo().frame("uploadFile"); // used iframe's id as locator inside frame()`

then, to fetch the input element, use the xpath `//input[@name='file']`

Do not forget to navigate away from the iframe after you are done interacting with this iframe. To navigate to default frame, use `driver.switchTo().defaultContent();`

Comment: Upvote for noticing the `iframe`. Not sure what language the OP is using, but this will have to be done with any bindings or `selenium-ide`

Comment: Yeah, my approach is valid for Java, OP hasn't mentioned what language is the question for.

Comment: driver.switchTo().frame("/sourcing_sit19/loan/uploadImportLoans.pe");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='file']"));

Comment: oops, try the id `"uploadFile"` inside `frame()` instead of src

Comment: I am using selenium using Java

Comment: Ok. replace the src with id of iframe

Comment: @bitan great. I'll update my answer as I made a small mistake. You can mark this answer as accepted.

Comment: after performing some actions on that frame I used driver.switchTo().defaultContent(); but i am getting an error Modal dialog present

Comment: after performing the action, are you expecting any popup's or alerts? usually this error is thrown when a popup or alert was found and selenium throws an exception and closes the modal. You need to modify the `unexpectedAlertBehaviour` property of the browser, so the selenium throws the exception and you see the modal window

Comment: I am just opening the browse window and using robot class to upload a file and then click ok

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```
//Going inside of the iframe
driver.switchTo().frame("uploadFile");

//Getting file input webelement
WebElement input=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//form[@name='fileUploadFrm']//input[@name='file']"));

//Sending file path using sendkeys method
input.sendKeys("filepath");

//Switch back to default
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

**Exception handling:** Modal dialog present exception will be thrown when an alert appeared and we are not handling it. If the alert doesn't appear every time place below after your operations.

```
try { 
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
alert.accept();
//if alert present, accept and move on.
 }
catch (NoAlertPresentException e) {
//do what you normally would if you didn't have the alert.
 }
```

Let me know if it works for you

Comment: driver.switchTo().defaultContent()

Comment: driver.switchTo().defaultContent()  after this i am getting an exception Modal dialog present: